# Rotate images on DropZone before upload

Tags: image-processing, dropzone.js

Is there a way to provide the user a way to rotate the image before upload on DropZone?

Answer (score -1):

No, drop zone does not proved client side image rotation. It can be implemented once the file is on the server though.